# Unable to build keycloak-themes and keycloak-guides

Tags: java, maven, keycloak

I would like to build the `Keycloak` project. I've checked out the `18.0.0` tag and also `main` but I'm getting the `keycloak-themes` and `keycloak-guides` projects fail to build.

I'm using Java 11 and have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/docs/building.md).

I can successfully build `17.0.0`.

**Command**

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

**keycloak-guides**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.5:process-asciidoc (server-asciidoc-to-html) on project keycloak-guides: Execution server-asciidoc-to-html of goal org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.5:process-asciidoc failed: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ArgumentError) asciidoctor: FAILED: C:/Users/michael.haywood/IdeaProjects/keycloak/docs/guides/target/generated-guides/server/index.adoc: Failed to load AsciiDoc document - invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :keycloak-guides
```

**keycloak-themes**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:npm (npm-install-common) on project keycloak-themes: Failed to run task: 'npm ci --no-optional --ignore-scripts' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -4058 (Exit value: -4058) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :keycloak-themes
```

Are there any other prerequisites when building `Keycloak` from the source code?

Comment: Can you run `mvn clean install -e -DskipTests`?

Comment: @LajosArpad After having these issues I decided to try `17.0.0` and it built correctly. I went back to `18.0.0` and ran your command and now it is building correctly too. I'll keep the question open for the moment for if the problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

keycloak-guides generates the documentation for keycloak. You have to set UTF-8 as the default encoding type in the Windows environment.
Try setting **MAVEN_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8** in System Environment Variable.

[Edit System Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl92R.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Am currently using Ubuntu 23.04. I ran `sudo apt install maven` in the terminal and it worked fine for me.